# Maintaining facing direction at the end of a movement

Tags: unity, 2d, android, animation, movement

I want to make my 2D top-down walking animation stop and revert to the idle animation while continuing to face in the same direction as the previous movement.

For example, when I go up then stop, my character should continue to look up. If I go down, it should continue to look down.

I use `lastmoveX` and `lastmoveY` floats for idle and for walking I use `moveX` and `moveY` floats. `moveX` and `moveY` change when I move with the joystick, but `lastmoveX` and `lastmoveY` do not change, and I don't know how to fix this.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D myRB;
    private Animator myAnim;
    public Joystick joystick;
    public MoveByTouch controller;

  

    [SerializeField]
    private float speed;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        myRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        myAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();

    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        myRB.velocity = new Vector2(joystick.Horizontal, joystick.Vertical) * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        myAnim.SetFloat("moveX", myRB.velocity.x);
        myAnim.SetFloat("moveY", myRB.velocity.y);

        if(joystick.Horizontal == 1 || joystick.Horizontal == -1 || joystick.Vertical == 1 || joystick.Vertical == -1)
        {
            myAnim.SetFloat("lastMoveX", joystick.Horizontal);
            myAnim.SetFloat("lastMoveY", joystick.Vertical);
        }

       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your joystick is never hitting *exactly* +-1 on either axis. maybe it hits 0.999, which is far enough away that `joystick.Horizontal == 1` would report "false", fail the `if`, and never execute the code that updates the `lastMove` variables. (This is why we have to be careful about comparing floating point numbers for exact equality)

Have you tried making the `if` condition more permissive, to trigger on any non-zero input? Something like this should do decently:

```
void Update ()
{
    myRB.velocity = new Vector2(joystick.Horizontal, joystick.Vertical) * speed;

    myAnim.SetFloat("moveX", myRB.velocity.x);
    myAnim.SetFloat("moveY", myRB.velocity.y);

    if(!Mathf.Approximately(joystick.Horizontal, 0) || !Mathf.Approximately(joystick.Vertical, 0))
    {
        myAnim.SetFloat("lastMoveX", joystick.Horizontal);
        myAnim.SetFloat("lastMoveY", joystick.Vertical);
    }       
}
```

(I deleted the `* Time.deltaTime` from your velocity calculation, as it is not appropriate to use there)

Comment: Yeah it worked thanks for help

Comment: You can click the checkmark icon next to the answer to mark it as "Accepted" if it solves your problem.